# Converter a complex MySQL query spatial calculation into Laravel Eloquent ORM query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm querying my database that finds the points on a map closest to a user within a given amount of time. The lat/lon are stored in a POINT column called `coords`. The table left joins on the user table so I can get the corresponding name.

The query works fine in MySql workbench. However I am struggling to convert it to an Eloquent based query. I'd prefer not to us `RAW` since it doesn't' offer the protections that Eloquent chained based methods offer.

I get errors like "us" and "id" column not found for the aliased column name us.id as an example. Among various others.

Here is MySQL query with the variables that the equivalent model should take.

```
// Some variables 
SET @orig_latitude = 1.234;
SET @orig_longitude = 5.678;
SET @radius = 500;

// Constants
SET @earth_size_size_in_miles = 3956;

//My query
SELECT us.name, ls.user_id, ls.coords, ls.lastseen_at AS lasttime,
    (  @earth_size_size_in_miles
                        * ACOS( COS(RADIANS(@orig_latitude))
                        * COS(RADIANS(ST_Y(coords)))
                        * COS(RADIANS(ST_X(coords))
                        - RADIANS(@orig_longitude) )
                        + SIN(RADIANS(@orig_latitude))
                        * SIN(RADIANS(ST_Y(coords)))
        )
    ) AS distance
FROM
    last_seens ls
LEFT JOIN
    users us ON ls.user_id = us.id
WHERE
     ls.lastseen_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE
HAVING
    DISTANCE < @radius
ORDER BY
    DISTANCE;
```

Here is just one of my failed attempts to at least get it working, but nothing will work.

```
$lat = 1.234;
$lon = 5.678;

$radius = 500;
$earth_size_size_in_miles = 3956;

$results = DB::table('last_seens AS ls')
    ->select('us.name', 'ls.user_id', 'ls.lastseen_at AS lasttime', DB::raw('( ?
                                            * ACOS( COS(RADIANS(?))
                                            * COS(RADIANS(ST_Y(coords)))
                                            * COS(RADIANS(ST_X(coords))
                                            - RADIANS(?) )
                                            + SIN(RADIANS(?))
                                            * SIN(RADIANS(ST_Y(coords)))
                            )
                        ) AS distance ', [$earth_size_size_in_miles, $lat, $lon, $lat]))
    ->leftJoin('users us', 'user_id ', '=', 'us.id')
    ->where(' ls.lastseen_at', '>=', 'NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE')
    ->havingRaw('DISTANCE < ?', [$radius])
    ->orderBy('DISTANCE')
    ->get();
```

The users table is the standard, out-of-the-box users table that comes with Laravel.

My LastSeens migration:

```
Schema::create('last_seens', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->bigIncrements('id')->unsigned();
                $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
                $table->point('coords');
                $table->timestamp('lastseen_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
            });

DB::statement("CREATE SPATIAL INDEX sx_last_seen_coords ON last_seens(coords);");
DB::statement("CREATE INDEX ts_last_seen_timestamp ON last_seens(lastseen_at);");
DB::statement("CREATE INDEX ix_last_seen_user_id ON last_seens(user_id);");
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE last_seens ADD CONSTRAINT fk_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;");
```

Any help?

Comment: Did your migration work though? Because I would assume that `$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();` should be a `bigInteger`. Also, when I run into errors like this, I normally check if the query works but running the raw sql query inside a DB::select. Maybe give it a try, just to see if it works in laravel? Of course, the variables have to passed.

Comment: Yes, the migrations work and I can run standard queries.

Comment: I see. In any case, I think it's important for data types to be consistent across tables to make full use of the indexing. And I didn't mean standard queries, I meant to run this raw SQL inside a `DB::select` as in `DB::select(" SELECT us.name, ls.user_id, ls.coords, ls.lastseen_at AS l.... ")` without eloquent joins and wheres. If you know what I mean. Thought I'd share because this method has helped me troubleshoot on many occasions.

Comment: ^ here I'm assuming that `id` in `user` table migration is `bigIncrements` since you said standard `user` table in laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You can't... yet.

While you can do simple aggregation in the ORM, you can't do this kind of math without running subqueries which will break the aggregation.

I might suggest offloading this work to your database instead then pull it back as a view.